# Filter out from a dataset rows where values of two variables are both = 0 in dplyr

Tags: r, database, dplyr

I have the following data:

```
x y z
A 0 0
B 1 0
C 0 2
D 1 1
E 2 0
F 2 3
G 1 3
H 0 0
I 3 3
```

I want to automatically filter out from this dataset all the rows where 'y' and 'z' assumes 0 values at the same time using dplyr (namely I want to exclude A and H only)

Comment: assuming `dat` is my dataset, `dat<-dat%>%filter(y!=0 & z!=0)` but that excludes also rows like B C E

Comment: just `df[rowSums(df[c(2:3)]) != 0,]`

Comment: I don't know how efficiently dplyr handles joins, but `anti_join(DF, data.frame(y=0,z=0))`... That's what I'd do with data.table, but in dplyr, maybe best to `filter`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
    filter(y != 0 | z != 0)

#   x y z
# 1 B 1 0
# 2 C 0 2
# 3 D 1 1
# 4 E 2 0
# 5 F 2 3
# 6 G 1 3
# 7 I 3 3
```

Answer (score 0):

If your dataset is stored in a `data.frame` called `df`

You can with `dplyr` do this :

```
filter(df, !y == 0, !z == 0)
```

which will return :

```
x y z
B 1 0
C 0 2
D 1 1
E 2 0
F 2 3
G 1 3
I 3 3
```

Comment: Thanks but I want to exclude A and H

Comment: @GabrieleMidolo I have edited, I think it's what you're looking for

Comment: That's using an "and" condition, but an "or" is relevant here.